# Can't Access String[] being passed in from RecieveRequest in Windows Workflow 4.0

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

My workflow is designed with a `String[]` parameter.
I am using a Windows Workflow Service project.

I have:

- a Sequence
- a Receive Request
- a Send Response

I have the receive request set up to take a `String[]`.  I pass in values, but I have tried many things to try to access this `String[]`.  I have tries Assign and get invalid syntax messages. The parameter in the receive request does not seem to be global, which is really counter intuitive.

How do get my sequence members to gain access to this `String[]` paramter that was passed in?

I have googled for the last hour on this and haven't been finding any answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable of string array type at the sequance level at variable section tab and assign it to receive activity content- content definition- message. You will then able to use request argument at whole workflow.